# Least prime $p_n$ such that $p_{n+1}-p_n\geq k$

Tags: number-theory, prime-gaps

I define $\rho(k)$ to be the least prime $p_n$ such that $p_{n+1}-p_n\geq k$.

Since every number in the set $\{(k+1)!+2, (k+1)!+3, (k+1)!+4, \cdots, (k+1)!+(k+1)\}$ is composite, we have that $\rho(k)\leq (k+1)!+1$.

Are there better bounds for it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain more about your proof.  Thanks!  Genuinely curious.  My first thought was would this same proof work with "primorial" or $p_n\# := p_n p_{n-1} \cdots p_1$ in place of everywhere a factorial is used.  You can even do $(k+1)\#$ and that means product all primes $\leq k+1$.

Comment: Yes, some information is missing from your proof.  Please provide reference or fill in the blanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that there are not going to be results that apply for small numbers; everything is about "sufficiently large" numbers. However, see

KEVIN FORD, BEN GREEN, SERGEI KONYAGIN, JAMES MAYNARD, AND TERENCE TA0

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.5029v3.pdf